Enforcing Custom Transfer Logic in Move Modules for Aptos Blockchain
I am working on a custom coin Move module for the Aptos blockchain and need to ensure that all transfers of a custom coin type use a specific transfer function that I will define. This function could include custom logic for fees, restrictions(e.g. kyc), etc.
The challenge I'm facing is how to enforce the use of this custom transfer function and prevent users from bypassing it by calling standard functions such as aptos_framework::coin::transfer or aptos_framework::aptos_account::transfer_coins. I want to ensure that the custom logic cannot be sidestepped.
Could anyone provide insights or examples of how to architect this module to enforce the use of a custom transfer function for a coin in Move?

This seems relatively simple to achieve in SUI move using the standard object transfer function

Aptos has launched its dispatchable fungible tokens where you can create custom withdraw/transfer functionality overwriting the default functions.
module my_addr::my_fungible_asset_example {
// ...
public fun withdraw<T: key>(
    store: Object<T>,
    amount: u64,
    transfer_ref: &TransferRef,
): FungibleAsset {
    // Your custom logic here
}

public fun deposit<T: key>(
    store: Object<T>,
    fa: FungibleAsset,
    transfer_ref: &TransferRef,
) {
    // Your custom logic here
}
// ...}

Here's a working example of taxed assets where on every transfer - 10% tax is sent to the deployer account):
https://github.com/aptos-labs/move-by-examples/blob/main/taxed-fungible-asset/move/sources/taxed_fa.move
Read more about the docs: https://aptos.dev/en/build/smart-contracts/fungible-asset#dispatchable-fungible-asset-advanced
AIP (Aptos Improvement Prosposal): https://github.com/aptos-foundation/AIPs/blob/main/aips/aip-73.md
